# how to download zip file from google Drive to colab

Tags: google-colaboratory

I have shared link form `google-drive` and I need to downloaded into my colab
I use this code but it's not working

```
!gdown https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DAQsttkUzc8iPhQMeLNqssuTpzryCDL1/view?usp=sharing
```

this is the file

> lian-v20.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I believe that zip file already placed in your google drive.
Now if you want to access zip file from google drive to google colab then you have to mount your google drive to the google colab. Once you have have with mounting then write this piece of code in your google colab

```
from zipfile import ZipFile

with ZipFile('/content/drive/MyDrive/SHISHU==folder/Start/HELLO_TEST.zip', 'r') 
as zipObj: # path where your zip file found

zipObj.extractall('/content/drive/MyDrive/TRAIN_SET') # path where you want to 
extract your zip file and save
```